# How Server Page Language contribute in Ease of use or Usability?

Tags: php, web-services

This site is used to compare some CMS " content mangement Systems "
http://www.cmsmatrix.org

and this feature "Server Page Language" under the ease of use how this feature contribute in usability?php, ASP, .. ??

Answer (score 1):

Which server side language you choose **doesn't** affect ease of use or usability of a CMS in any meaningful way.

Comment: please check the url I edited the post ,, that website put the server page lang undr the ease of use , I think thy have a reeason.

Comment: @Iman25: it will be easier to use for you *if* you have experience with the server side language at hand *and* if you are planning to modify the code base directly. But it doesn't directly influence the ease of use of the CMS system *itself*.